# How many cafes at least have to be asked in a random sample?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The daily turnover $X$ of Cafes has the expected value $ \mu_X = 600 $ Euro and the standard deviation $ \sigma_X = 30 $ Euro.

How many cafes at least have to be asked in a random sample, so that $\overline{X}_n$ deviates from $\mu_X$ with a probability of at least $95\%$ by less than $12$ euros?

$$$$

Do we use here the Chebyshev inequality?

We have that $P(|\overline{X}_n-\mu_X|<12)=95\% \Rightarrow P(|\overline{X}_n-600|<12)=0.95$, right?

It holds that $P(|\overline{X}_n-600|<12)=1-P(|\overline{X}_n-600|\geq 12)\geq 1-\frac{\sigma_X^2}{12^2}$ by the Chebyshev inequality, or not?

How could we continue?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a confidence interval? No you don't need Chebyshev's inequality

Comment: Ah ok! So we have that $$P\left (\frac{\overline{X}-\mu_X}{\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq 12\right )>0.95$$ or do you not mean it in that way? @DavidQuinn

Answer (score 2):

A $\color{red}{95}$% confidence interval for the mean, based on a random sample of size $n$, assuming a Normal Distribution, is $$\bar{X}\pm\color{red}{1.96}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Therefore you can solve for $n$ the inequality $$1.96\frac{30}{\sqrt{n}}<12$$

Comment: Ah ok! How do we know that we have here a Normal distribution? Or do we just assume that? Also at the next question, it is asked the following: After a random survey of $500$ cafes you will receive a realized arithmetic mean of $x_{500} = 690$ euros. Does this result surprise you according to your calculations above? From the above calculations we have that if we ask at least $25$ cafes the mean with not deviate from $600$ by more that $12$ euros, and this happens also here were $500$ are asked, or not?

Comment: We are assuming the Central Limit Theorem applies. I don't understand the rest of your question. Perhaps you need to ask a new question and use the exact wording.

Comment: Ah ok! I mean that asking $500$ cafes we get the median $690$ which deviates from $\mu$ by more than $12$ euros. Why does this hold? Should it deviates by less than 12 euros, since n must be at least 25 ?

Comment: if the mean of a sample of 500 is 690, you can calculate the 95% confidence interval for the mean. Because of the increased $n$, the width is a lot smaller than before. Obviously 600 is a long way outside this, so 600 could not be the true population mean (assuming the SD is correct)

Comment: So, is it always like that? If we take a much bigger number as the smallest possible n, then the meadian that we calculate doesn't any more deviates by less than 12 (in this case)? $$$$ Do we do the same method here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729065/tossing-of-coins-distribution

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, and I don't understand the wording of the question you link to.